# How to use a GUI form created in IntelliJ in another program (e.g. Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, intellij-idea, intellij-15

How would you take a .java and .form file that was created in IntelliJ and run it in another program, such as Eclipse?

Also, is there a way to make the GUI Form editor actually write all of the code into the class file?

Comment: And please don't say just use Eclipse's WindowBuilder. I find Eclipse pretty annoying.

Comment: Do you not have the .java file that created the .class file?

Comment: Thanks, didn't see that question.

Answer (score 1):

The .form file is only understood by IntelliJ IDEA; there aren't any tools to allow editing IntelliJ IDEA .form files in other IDEs. The .class file is just a Java class; you can use it just like any other Java library. It contains the entire data for the form; the .form file is not needed at runtime.

The GUI Designer can generate source code as well. You can enable this in Settings | Editor | GUI Designer | Generate GUI into...

Comment: So could I open the class file in, say, Eclipse, and it would run just fine?

Comment: Yes, it will run just fine.